# Transparent UIView like photo gallery app in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, transparent

The default camera app has a photo gallery which has glossy and transparent look, especially the toolbar. One can see the image partially behind the toolbar. How is this achieved? Is it just by altering the opaque property of UIView? Any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the style of the status bar and the navigation bar.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated_
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated_];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
   [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
   [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated_
{
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated_];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
   [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to set the status bar style to UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent for a whole day and all I had to do was to send the message [self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES]! Cheers mate